# Show that the set of all periodic configurations over $Σ$ is dense in $X =Σ^{\mathbb N} $.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Consider the space $X := Σ^{\mathbb N} $ of all configurations over an alphabet $Σ$, equipped
> with the topology generated by the cylinder sets. A configuration $x = x_1x_2 · · ·
> $ is said to be periodic if there exists a positive integer $p$ such that $x_{i+p} = x_i$ for all $i ∈ \mathbb N$. For instance, the following configurations over the alphabet {$0, 1$} are periodic:
> $x := 00000000000000000000 · · ·
> $
> $y := 10010010010010010010 · · ·
> $
> Show that the set of all periodic configurations over $Σ$ is dense in $X$.

My attempt:

Definition: $D ⊆ X$ is dense in a set $E ⊆ X$ if $\overline{D \cap E} = E$

The cylinder sets $E := C(w) =$ {$x \in X: x_1x_2...x_n = w_1w_2...w_n$} is a subset of $X$, and forms a basis for a topology on $X$. And $\bar{E} =$ {$x \in X: x_1x_2...x_n \not= w_1w_2...w_n$}.

Let $D :=$ {$x \in X: x_{i+p} = x_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N, p > 0$}. And $\bar{D} =${$x \in X: x_{i+p} \not= x_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N, p > 0$}.

So, $\overline{D \cap E} ⊆ \bar{D} \cap \bar{E} = \phi ⊆ E$

Now, how to prove that $E ⊆ \overline{D \cap E}$?

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Use the following characterization of density instead: D is dense if every nonempty basic open set contains an element from D. So what you have to show here is that every cylinder set contains a periodic sequence.

Comment: Could you please show me how?

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=w_1w_2\ldots w_n\in\Sigma$, and let $C(w)$ be the corresponding cylinder set. Each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ can be written in the form $k=an+r$ for some non-negative integer $a_k$ and $r_k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $x_k=w_{r_k}$. Then

$$x=w_1w_2\ldots w_nw_1w_2\ldots w_nw_1w_2\ldots w_n\ldots$$

is periodic with period $n$:

$$k+n=a_kn+r_k+n=(a_k+1)n+r_k\,,$$

so $a_{k+n}=a_k+1$, $r_{k+n}=r_k$, and therefore $$x_{k+n}=w_{r_{k+n}}=w_{r_k}=x_k\,.$$ Thus, every cylinder set contains a periodic configuration. The cylinder sets are a base for the topology, so every non-empty open set contains a periodic configuration, and therefore set of periodic configurations is dense in $X$.